# By using Jetpack Navigation Compnent

Tags: android

I couldn't get any idea or anything online so here I am. I'm using the jetpack navigation component and I want to navigate from fragmentA to fragmentB, and then fragmentB will have bottomnavigation with different fragments such as fragmentC, fragmentD, fragmentE[image], and fragmentE have viewpagers with different fragments such as fragmentF, fragmentG, fragmentH

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: while clicking fragmentB after that how to implement bottomNavigationBar having with navigationHostFragment inside fragmentB using jetPack

Comment: @UD.. You can make another navigation graph for your need.

Answer (score 0):

create navigation as your requirement as:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:name="com.package.share.ShareFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_share"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_share" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:name="com.package.SendFragment"
        android:label="@string/comments"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send" />
</navigation>
```

and navigate to the fragment with respective menu and navHostFragment

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/user_navigation" />
```

now find your nav host fragment and set up your configuration...

hope this helps.......happy coding